# The retrieval time for the Apache Ignite cache is too long

Tags: java, caching, ignite, apacheignite

I want to use Apache Ignite as a caching layer. I'm using Ignite thick client. I've inserted up to 400,000 records into the server for caching. However, when retrieving data, it takes 2-3 seconds. How can I reduce this delay? Additionally, when attempting to load more than 400,000 records, they're not getting cached. I'm trying to load over 10 million data onto the server at startup. What could be the issue?
Please give me a clear solution. I'm new to Ignite.

**Server Configuration for reference:**

```
public class MemoryAndCacheMonitoring {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("Instance");
        cfg.setConsistentId("Node");

        DataStorageConfiguration storageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();
        DataRegionConfiguration regionCfg = new DataRegionConfiguration();
        regionCfg.setMaxSize(6L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
        regionCfg.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        regionCfg.setInitialSize(4L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
        regionCfg.setMetricsEnabled(true); 

        storageCfg.setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration(regionCfg);
        cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(storageCfg);

        CacheConfiguration<String, String> CacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>();
        CacheCfg.setName("myCache");
        CacheCfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
        CacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
        CacheCfg.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);

        cfg.setCacheConfiguration(CacheCfg);
        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);

        Ignite igniteServer = Ignition.start(cfg);
        igniteServer.cluster().state(ClusterState.ACTIVE);

        IgniteCache<String, String> myCache = igniteServer.getOrCreateCache("myCache");
        igniteServer.resetLostPartitions(Arrays.asList("myCache"));
        igniteServer.cluster().baselineAutoAdjustEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

**Function for streaming bulk data:**

```
 @Async
    public CompletableFuture<Void> processAllRecords() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        List<ProductLines> records = productLinesRepo.findRecordsWithPanNotNull();
        if (!records.isEmpty()) {
            igniteCacheService.streamBulkData("myCache", records);
            totalProcessedRecords += records.size();
            logger.info("Processed {} records", totalProcessedRecords);
            System.out.println("Processed batch of records until now: " + totalProcessedRecords);
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        logger.info("Total time taken for processing all records: {} milliseconds", totalTime);

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }
```

**Controller for cache retrieval:**

```
 @GetMapping("/getCache/{cacheName}/{panNumber}")
    public Map<String, ProductLines> getCachebyId(@PathVariable String cacheName, @PathVariable String panNumber) {
        IgniteCache<String, ProductLines> cache = cacheService.getCache(cacheName);

        if (cache != null) {
            Map<String, ProductLines> thatoneCache = new HashMap<>();

            // Iterate over all entries in the cache
            for (Cache.Entry<String, ProductLines> entry : cache) {
                if(entry.getKey().toString().equals(panNumber))
                    thatoneCache.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            return thatoneCache;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Requested Cache '" + cacheName + "' cannot be found"); // Handle error appropriately

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterating over the entire cache is never a good idea

You have the key, use it to retrieve the entry.

```java
ProductLines res = cache.get(panNumber);
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Could you also explain why I am unable to load more than 400,000 records? Up to 400,000 records, the metrics display:

^-- CPU [CPUs=12, curLoad=0.27%, avgLoad=0.31%, GC=0%] ^-- Heap [used=147MB, free=90.48%, comm=377MB]

However, after surpassing 400,000 records, the metrics indicate:

` java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.`

Could this be related to the server configuration?

Comment: @AkashDharshan looks like you load all records into memory at once - `List<ProductLines> records`. Consider loading an inserting them into Ignite in smaller batches.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Pavel Tupitsyn contributed also be aware that by iterating over the entire cache you are also loading the thick client memory with the data that is currently distributed out to your N server nodes! A cache is a key / value store. It works very well and very fast for the retrieval of the value for any known key as any single key is always at worst 1 level of indirection any from the client that is making the request. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about that. I've corrected my mistake.